# Can someone explain why boostrap 5 mx-auto d-block, is not working with a fluid image?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

My code is very simple and I'm confused to why it isn't working, I removed any other external css from the page that could be interrupting it and still the image won't centre inside of my column. I have looked about and the code that I'm using should work so I'm having trouble understanding, am i missing something obvious ?

I also tried placing my image inside of div tag and centring that but it didn't work either.

```
    <div class="container border border-2 mb-5 mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 bg-light text-black">
                <h1> Sign Up </h1><br>
                <form action="signup.php" method="post" class="was-validated">
                    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                        <label for="username" class="form-label">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
                        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="log_in_form.php">LogIn</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="signup.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="golf">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image is already centered horizontally inside the `.col` (because `.img-fluid` gives it 100% width), so I assume you want to vertically center, which means you want to affect the `y` axis not the `x`. It will need to be inside a [flexbox container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) to work,

Try `.img-fluid.my-auto` inside `.d-flex`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container border border-2 mb-5 mt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 bg-light text-black">
      <h1> Sign Up </h1><br>
      <form action="signup.php" method="post" class="was-validated">
        <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
          <label for="username" class="form-label">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="log_in_form.php">LogIn</a>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 d-flex">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="img-fluid my-auto" alt="golf">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```